# Overlap an element over another element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make such a stuff
[image]

But somehow I got something like the one below(Please ignore the color, font family for now)
[image]

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrEfm/1/).
HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>Instagram Photo</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
     background-color:red;
     width:60%;
     margin-left:20%;
     height:30px;
     z-index:3;
     position:static;
}
.box p{
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    line-height:30px;
}
hr {
    border-top: 1px solid red; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue; 
    z-index:-1;
    margin-top:-15px;
    position:static;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `position: static` to `position: relative` for the box.

[**CSS-Tricks reference**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)

> z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than
>   static (the default).

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
.box p {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 30px;
}
hr {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>Instagram Photo</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make it exactly like the image you put.
Whenever you want to put an HTML element above or beneath another element, use the `z-index` property. The more the value of the `z-index`, it will be more on the above, and vice versa

```css
.box{
    background-color: #F8931F;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40px;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
}

.seperator{
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F8931F;
    top: 52px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">instagram photos</div>
<div class="seperator"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to use `:after` for the border.

```css
.box{
 height:30px;
 z-index:3;
 position:static;
}
.box p{
 background-color:red;
text-align:center;
color:white;
line-height:30px;
margin: 0;
 margin-left:20%;
 width:60%;
}
.box:after{
border-top: 1px solid red; 
border-bottom: 1px solid blue; 
content: '';
display: block;
z-index:-1;
top:-15px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>Instagram Photo</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nrEfm/50/